# Find max trips per day from DataFrame in Java - Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

Environment: Java 1.8, VM Cloudera Quickstart.
I have data into Hadoop hdfs from a csv file. Each row represents a bus route.

```
    id      vendor    start_datetime   end_datetime    trip_duration_in_sec
    17534   A         1/1/2013 12:00   1/1/2013 12:14  840
    68346   A         1/1/2013 12:13   1/1/2013 12:18  300
    09967   B         1/1/2013 12:34   1/1/2013 12:39  300
    09967   B         1/1/2013 12:44   1/1/2013 12:51  420
    09967   A         1/1/2013 12:54   1/1/2013 12:56  120
   .........
   .........
```

So, i want for every day, to find the hour that each vendor (A and B) has the most bus routes. With java and spark.
A result could be:

```
1/1/2013 (Day 1) - Vendor A has 3 bus routes at 12:00-13:00 hour. (That time 12:00-13:00, vendor A had the most bus routes..)
1/1/2013 (Day 1) - Vendor B has 2 bus routes at 12:00-13:00 hour. (That time 12:00-13:00, vendor B had the most bus routes..)
....
```

Mu java code is:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

Dataset<Row> ds;
ds.groupBy(functions.window(col("start_datetime"), "1 hour").count().show();
```

But i cant find in which hour are the max routes per day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar in Java so I tried to explain it in Scala.

The key to find out the hour of max routes per day per vendor, is to count by `(vendor, day, hour)`, then aggregate by `(vendor, day)` to calculate the hour corresponding to maximum cnt of each group. The `day` and the `hour` of each record could be parsed by `start_datetime`.

```scala
val df = spark.createDataset(Seq(
("17534","A","1/1/2013 12:00","1/1/2013 12:14",840),
("68346","A","1/1/2013 12:13","1/1/2013 12:18",300),
("09967","B","1/1/2013 12:34","1/1/2013 12:39",300),
("09967","B","1/1/2013 12:44","1/1/2013 12:51",420),
("09967","A","1/1/2013 12:54","1/1/2013 12:56",120)
)).toDF("id","vendor","start_datetime","end_datetime","trip_duration_in_sec")

df.rdd.map(t => {
    val vendor = t(1)
    val day = t(2).toString.split(" ")(0)
    val hour = t(2).toString.split(" ")(1).split(":")(0)
    ((vendor, day, hour), 1)
})
// count by key
.aggregateByKey(0)((x: Int, y: Int) =>x+y, (x: Int, y: Int) =>x+y) 
.map(t => {
    val ((vendor, day, hour), cnt) = t;
    ((vendor, day), (hour, cnt))
})
// solve the max cnt by key (vendor, day)
.foldByKey(("", 0))((z: (String, Int), i: (String, Int)) => if (i._2 > z._2) i else z)
.foreach(t => println(s"${t._1._2} - Vendor ${t._1._1} has ${t._2._2} bus routes from ${t._2._1}:00 hour."))
```

Comment: Lets simplify this. Assume we have only 1 vendor, A. For every day, how can i find the hour that only vendor A has the most bus routes?

Comment: It's much the same. Firstly to count by `(day, hour)`, then to aggregate by `day`.